# MultiDatePicker doesn't display selected dates correctly if number of dates exceeds 92

Tags: ios, swiftui, multidatepicker

I want to display multiple dates using MultiDatePicker.
At this time, if the selected date exceeds 92, it is not displayed properly.

The testable code is very simple.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MultiDatePickerTest: View {
    @State var selectedDates: Set<DateComponents> = []
    
    var body: some View {
        MultiDatePicker("sample", selection: $selectedDates)
    }
}

struct MultiDatePickerTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MultiDatePickerTest()
    }
}
```

You can find out by changing the number of selectedDate when creating a MultiDatePicker as above.

Up to 92 items are displayed well. For example, 92 days from October 1 to December 31. But when I select 93 days from October 1 to January 1, 2024, it doesn't display the selected date correctly. (Changing the year is not the cause.)

I attach a video. If I select more than 93 days, it appears to display the selected date when scrolling, but you can see that it disappears immediately.

Any idea what might be the issue?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hf01EK3zo-UoG21MKmhIEM54-oH9Nr8A/view?usp=sharing